# apt update package, also write pre-update and post-update package version to a file using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I know we can use the `apt` module to update a package. I want to write the pre and post update version to a file (for keeping record only).

```yaml
- name: Upgrade package(s)
  ansible.builtin.apt:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: latest
    update_cache: true
    only_upgrade: true
  loop: "{{ packages }}"
```

But the apt udpate standard output does not contain the pre udpate version.
It's also difficult to parse the post update version from standard output.

Is there any good method?

Comment: The recommended approach is to use package_facts before and after an update. No need for utilizing the apt module, registering and parsing output. If fact caching is enabled it becomes written into a file automatically.

Comment: I would also add that you can (and generally should) pass the list of packages directly to the module via the  `name` parameter instead of running it in a loop to [improve performance](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#notes). The same is true for the other package managers as well, not only for `apt`.

Answer (score 4):

The recommended approach is to use [`package_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html) before and after an update. No need for utilizing the `apt` module, registering and parsing output. If [Caching facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#caching-facts) is enabled it becomes written into a file automatically.

For an **`ansible.cfg`** file

```ini
[defaults]

...

inject_facts_as_vars    = True

fact_path               = /etc/ansible/facts.d
fact_caching            = yaml
fact_caching_connection = /tmp/ansible/facts_cache
fact_caching_timeout    = 129600
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Backup package facts, it is assumed they were gathered already
    delegate_to: controlnode.example.com
    copy:
      src: "/tmp/ansible/facts_cache/{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      dest: "/tmp/ansible/facts_cache/{{ inventory_hostname }}.before"
      remote_src: true
    failed_when: false

  - name: Upgrade package(s)
    package: # or apt or yum ...
      name: '*'
      state: latest

  - package_facts:
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
PLAY [test] ****************************************************************

TASK [Backup package facts, it is assumed they were gathered already] ******
changed: [controlnode.example.com]

TASK [Upgrade package(s)] **************************************************
changed: [test.example.com]

TASK [package_facts] *******************************************************
```

and on the Control Node

```bash
diff -h /tmp/ansible/facts_cache/test.example.com.before /tmp/ansible/facts_cache/test.example.com
2102c2102
<     release: 81.git78c0348.el7_9
---
>     release: 82.git78c0348.el7_9
3535c3535
<     release: 5.el7_9.11
---
>     release: 5.el7_9.12
3775c3775
<     version: 2023d
---
>     version: 2024a
3782c3782
<     version: 2023d
---
>     version: 2024a
```

One may also have a look into

```yaml
- name: Show Package Facts
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages }}"
```

as well into the generated files in order to get familiar with the content and data structures.